# Html/ Javascript login

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am in the middle of making a one use login using javascript to create if else statements to see if the input from my html form matches the correct username and login. i haven't been able to find out what the problem is but something is keeping it from loading the link i have it set to open when you use the correct login or even the wrong password text.

KEYNOTE : most of my code is from w3schools

```html
</div> <!-- /container -->
      
      <div align="center" class = "container">
      
         <form class = "form-signin" role = "form" id ="LoginF"
               action ="" method="post"
      <h4> </h4>
            <input type = "text" class = "form-control" 
               name = "username" id ="username" placeholder = "username = Johnny Appleseed" 
               required autofocus color="#00DD19"><br> 
            &nbsp;<input type = "password" class = "form-control"
               name = "password" id="password" placeholder = "password = Yum @pple$" required>
            <br><button class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type = "submit" 
               name = "login" id = "login" onclick="myFunction()">Login</button>
         <script>
 function myFunction() { 
 String username =
  document.getElementById("username");
 String password =
  document.getElementById("password");
 
  String Cusername = "TeacherLogin";
  String Cpassword = "Hapke";
  String Wrong = "Wrong user name or password";
  if (username = Cusername){
   
   if (password = Cpassword){ 
   window.open("https://mail.google.com/mail/");
   }else {System.out.print(Wrong);}
  }else{System.out.print(Wrong);}
 }
 
 
 </script>
```

Comment: `String Cusername = "TeacherLogin";`  is not JS syntax...

Comment: It seems like you are mixing up Java and JavaScript. Those are two completely different languages. In JavaScript, you can't declare variables with `String`, you can't print with `System.out.print` and you can't compare variables using a single `=` (but the last one is also the case for Java).

Comment: You are trying to write Java in your `script` tag. Java is not a scripting language and not the same thing as JavaScript, which is what you should be writing.

Comment: Also feel compelled to say: don’t use JavaScript to do login. JavaScript is available to the user/bots.

Answer (score 1):

Your mixing JavaScript and Java together, which are completely different.  Found out that you're using Java to declare your variables, redirect and print to console. Instead, change all this `String variable_name = "string here";` occurrent in your code to `var variable_name = "string here";`, and replace `System.out.print(Wrong);` with `console.log(Wrong);`.

Note: You don't specify the data type in JavaScript. JavaScript determines the data type of a variable by examining the type of value you assign.

Update the portion of your code with this code below:

```
  <form class="form-signin" role="form" id="LoginF" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return processForm(event);">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username = Johnny Appleseed" required autofocus color="#00DD19"><br> &nbsp;
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password = Yum @pple$" required>
    <br><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="login" id="login" onclick=>Login</button>
  </form><br><br><br><br>
  <script>
      function processForm(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //stop the form from submitting to server
        var username =
          document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password =
          document.getElementById("password").value;

        var Cusername = "TeacherLogin";
        var Cpassword = "Hapke";
        var Wrong = "Wrong user name or password";

        if (username == Cusername && password == Cpassword) {
          window.location.href = "https://mail.google.com/mail/";
        } else {
          console.log(Wrong);
        }
      }

    </script>
```

Link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1ktge8x/1/) test.

Comment: k that worked the only thing is that now when i load the page it auto opens the link

Comment: In your code change this `if (password = Cpassword)` to `if (password == Cpassword)`. In JavaScript use `==`, not `=`.

Comment: @Jacob Kiss Don't forget to read comments under your original question.

Comment: just saw that in my book when i went back to look over it

Comment: @Jacob Kiss Okey.

Comment: just made those aditional changes and it is back to doing nothing

Comment: @Jacob Kiss Write your code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and post the link here, so that I can have a look at it.

Comment: @Jacob Kiss I have updated my answer to reflect the new change.

Comment: so i added the changes you listed but now it gets stuck when i click log in

Comment: @Jacob Kiss If you don't have a server you can run it  locally in your machine.

Comment: @Jacob Kiss Check your code for typo, the updated code is working perfectly. You can comfirm that by running the code in JSFiddle link  I provided in my answer below.

Comment: i don't understand all i know is that when i copied the section of code you changed it worked. Thank you sooo much.

Comment: @Jacob Kiss Don't forget to mark the answer. Your welcome.

Answer (score 0):

just to get an idea...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps

```js
const
  UserName     = document.getElementById("user-name"),
  UserPassword = document.getElementById("user-password"),
  GoodUserName = 'TeacherLogin',
  GoodPassword = 'Hapke'
;

document.getElementById("bt-login").onclick = function()
{
  if (UserName.value===GoodUserName && UserPassword.value===GoodPassword ) {
    window.location.href("https://mail.google.com/mail/");
  }                     
  else {
    alert('Java language is not JavaScript language');
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="user-name"      type="text"        placeholder="username = Johnny Appleseed" />
<input id="user-password"  type="password"    placeholder="password = Yum @pple$" />

<button id="bt-login" >Login</button>
```

PS:

> KEYNOTE : most of my code is from w3schools.

sound very wrong